# Is it possible Identify invisible unicode characters in a string using System.Drawing namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, system.drawing

I am aiming to identify invisible Unicode characters in a string. I cannot use regex since there is no foolproof way to only match non-printable characters. My field needs to allow all unicode chars except these non-printable ones. I have gone through all answers related to it in SO. Kindly don't mark this as a duplicate.

As an alternative I am exploring if it is possible to identify if a string contains non-printable Unicode characters using `System.Drawing` namespace. My back-end is in C# .Net Core.

What I tried

```
        private static readonly Bitmap BMP = new Bitmap(1000, 1000);
        private static readonly Graphics GRAPHICS = Graphics.FromImage(BMP);
        private static readonly Font FONT = new Font("Arial", 20);
        private static readonly Rectangle RECT = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1000, 1000);

        public static bool IsNonPrintable(Graphics g, string str, Font font, Rectangle rect, StringFormat sf)
        {
            var sfTemp = sf.Clone() as StringFormat;
            var ranges = new CharacterRange[] { new CharacterRange(0, str.Length) };
            sfTemp.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(ranges);

            var regions = g.MeasureCharacterRanges(str, font, rect, sfTemp);
            if (regions != null && regions.Length > 0)
            {
                var size =  regions[0].GetBounds(g).Size;
                return size.Height == 0 && size.Width == 0;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

the results for some invisible/non-printable characters.

- SOFT HYPHEN https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ad/index.htm - TRUE
- LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm - TRUE
- RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200f/index.htm - TRUE
- MUSICAL SYMBOL BEGIN PHRASE https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d179/index.htm - FALSE
- HANGUL FILLER https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/003164/index.htm - FALSE
- TAG NUMBER SIGN https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e0023/index.htm - FALSE

Ideally all the results should have been TRUE. Is this even a viable approach to identify non-printable characters? Or can this be improved?

Comment: You mean if the font you are using cannot turn the unicode sequence into a glyph? Otherwise there's `Char.IsControl` to test for some special characters. Or more generally `Char.GetUnicodeCategory`.

Comment: I think you need to define what you mean by "non-printable" first. Your method checks if the characters have a zero-sized bounding box when displayed with a given font. That is a reasonable definition of "non-printable", but evidently, that is not the definition that you had in mind? Whatever font you are using had a non-zero sized bounding box for e.g. HANGUL FILLER, and you didn't expect that.

Comment: Also note that `string+=character` rendered with a specific font, may stay the same length or even shrink, while having a different appearance. Rendered text width shouldn't be used to test if the appearance of two strings is the same. So, what problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @Sweeper TBH I did not have a clear intention in mind. I am not too familiar with this namespace. But yes, your definition of non-printable sounds about right. Functionality wise, if it doesn't display in the browser, I take it as non-printable. Is there a specific font I am supposed to use here?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman thanks for that. I wasn't aware of it. My intention is that if a giving string contains only any of the characters in my examples, it needs to return TRUE. Currently it returns TRUE (as width and height is 0) for first three and the rest have a >0 width and height.

Comment: Looking at the characters list for [Arial](https://www.aivosto.com/fontitin/help/sample-all.html), I think your approach doesn't work possibly because Arial doesn't support HANGUL FILLER and the other characters that returned false, and this caused it to draw a question mark or something to a similar effect, which does not have a zero-sized bounding box. So for this to be correct for all Unicode code points, you'll need a font that supports everything. Anyway, I have the same question as Jeremy Lakeman - what problem are you trying to solve by finding these non-printable characters?

Comment: @Sweeper if I find that a string only contains these non-printable characters, I need to throw a validation error. If non these end up polluting the UI with blank strings everywhere. Of course using regex is the obvious choice, but it doesn't fully work for my case since I need to allow special chars in my string but exclude those with only non-printable characters.

Comment: That sounds like you should be finding characters that, when drawn, are completely transparent (so spaces would count), rather than having a 0 bounding box.

Comment: Pity that MeasureString is just a win32 dll wrapper. Maybe something like WPF's `GlyphTypeface.CharacterToGlyphMap` would tell you if something would be displayed. Not sure if there's a `Graphics` equivalent.

Comment: The Unicode Character Property \p{XPosixGraph} as defined in Perl seams to be what you are looking for. I don't know if .net has that property.